# wordpress image blog post thumbnail height stretch display issue

Tags: wordpress, post, stretch

I have an issue in my wordpress blog post thumbnail image. The height was stretch, I do the css height: auto; but still won't behave as expected.

[image: screenshot]

```css
.post-image img {
 height: auto;
}
```

```html
<?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) { //check for feature image ?>

  <div class="post-image">
   <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
  </div><!---end post image--> 
  
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: check if your height:auto; is overridden by someother, else try !important

Answer (score 0):

Use `<?php the_post_thumbnail(array(200x200)); ?>`
add height & width using array to apply to image. 
Still not resolved then css comes from any parent structure.

Comment: Hi mau, applying that array can be still responsive?

Comment: in an array it possible to make it auto or 100% width and height?